# WebSphere Remote MQ Clustering

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I have two machines - Machine 1 and Machine 2. Machine 1 has one queue manager QM1 and a broker(integration server) BR1 and Machine 2 has one queue manager QM2 and a broker(integration server) BR2 . I want to make a cluster between QM1 AND QM2. I had created a remote cluster queue named INVENTQ in QM2 .The problem is that I am able to successfully post any message on any queue manager and I am able to see the corresponding message on INVENTQ in QM2 . But I want the architecture to be in such a way that I am able to receive the message from the queue from any of the queue managers in addition to the queue manager in which the queue INVENTQ is created i.e QM2 . Can anybody guide me in this ?

Comment: Create it on both.

Answer (score 2):

MQ does not have a 'remote get' capability - ie you cannot use local bindings to a queue manager and get a message from another queue manager. If you want to do this, you need to use client bindings to go to the queue manger where the message resides directly.

At MQPUT time, a decision has to be made (on the putting queue manager), where to forward the message to (e.g. which local queue, or which transmission queue to pass it to another queue manager).

In a cluster setup, if you have a queue defined on one queue manager and put it the cluster, anyone from any of the clustered queue managers can put to it as though it was a local queue. However their MQPUTs result in the message arriving (via the cluster channels), onto the one particular instance. Therefore from a different queue manager whilst you can put the message to the queue, you cannot get it.

You could have a queue with the same name defined on multiple queue managers and clustered, as per @JoshMc's suggestion, but this means that at MQPUT time, the message is routed to one, and only one, instance of that queue - if it was routed to the remote queue manager clustered definition you still would not be able to get it from the local queue manager. Imagine you had a cluster of 3 qmgrs. You can create a clustered queue called 'FRED' in 2 of them. All of them can put to FRED - but 2 of them will default to put to their local queue only (unless you set CLWLUSEQ=ANY), the other will (usually) alternate between the 2 remote instances. Each queue will definitely have different messages on.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/Undestanding_on_MQ_Cluster_Work_Load_Management_Algorithm_and_Attributes?lang=en

Comment: Great write up Jason.  I was short on time :)

Comment: If I add the queue with the same name (INVENTQ) to both the queue managers in a cluster , then I guess that every queue manager would put the message in its local queue and the queue 'INVENTQ' in both the queue managers would have a different set of messages . I think this would violate the principle of cluster . Or else there could be chances that there would be conflict in creation of the queues with the same name in both the queue managers .

Comment: See edit above... 

I guess the question is what are you trying to achieve with your perceived setup. Why do you want 2 qmgrs each being able to retrieve messages from a queue. Is workload balancing? high availability? redundancy? etc

Comment: yes , I want high availability so that in case one of the queue managers gets down , I am able to receive the same set of messages using the other queue manager . Suppose if I deploy a BAR file in the cluster , then it should get deployed to both the queue managers so that if one of the queue managers gets down , I am able to retrieve it from the other queue manager .I checked we can achieve it from the multi instance queue managers but I guess that works in active passive mode but there is a requirement to do it in Active/Active mode .

Comment: Obviously you want to buy a mainframe so you get shared queue support.... Aside from that, once the message is on disk in a queue file, if the qmgr is offline you cannot access it. So for distributed, that leaves multi instance/HA as the only way to keep access to it during a failure. Dont forget you could run active/standby on one node and standby/active on the other, so both qmgrs stay alive and in times of trouble they both run on the same node